# comlen function in Java

Tags: java, c

in c or c++
the  function `comlen` is defined  such

```
int comlen(char *p,char *q){
   int i=0;
   while  *p && (*p++==*q++)
      i++;
   return i;
}
```

Is this code equivalent of this function?

```
int comlen(String s,String m){
   int  i=0;
   while (i<s.length() && s.charAt(i)==m.charAt(i)){
      i++;
   }
   return i;
}
```

Comment: Please stop tagging everything as algorithm!

Comment: They are functionally identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would I be correct in assuming this function returns how many characters are identical starting at the beginning of the string?

You may want to check out [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) `StringUtils` and its [`indexOfDifference`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#indexOfDifference(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method.

Otherwise, this function *should* work (but I haven't tested it):

```
public int comlen(CharSequence s, CharSequence m) {
    int end = s.length() > m.length() ? m.length() : s.length();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < end && s.charAt(i) == m.charAt(i)) {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Note that CharSequence is an interface that is used by `String`, `StringBuffer`, and `StringBuilder` rather than just `String`.

Answer (score 1):

The two are nearly equivalent. However, since C++ does not do bounds checking for you and Java does, you need to check for the end of either string in the Java example, rather than just checking for the end of s.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not equivalent. The Java function will fail with an exception if the first parameter is shorter than the second. The C/C++ function gives the correct result even in that case.

Comment: once you understand the problem, you'll understand how to fix it

Comment: we can use throws exception  or  enter constraints that both String are equal